# Webflux unit testing: call is not going inside .map and .flatMap

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, spring-webflux

I am writing unit testing for function calculate in webflux

```
@Override
    public Mono<SearchSessionAndETAResponse> calculate(DTO sessionRequest) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        List<GeospatialData> dataFromRedis =  getDataFromRedis(sessionRequest.getSessionId());
        return Mono.just(dataFromRedis)
                .map(data -> {
                    System.out.println("data::"+data);
                    return "entityIdentifiers";
                })
                .flatMap(entityIdentifiers -> {
                    System.out.println("entityIdentifiers::"+entityIdentifiers);
                    return etaService.entitiesEta("entityIdentifiers");
                })
                .map(wayPointRoute -> {
                    return searchSessionAndETAResponse;
                });
    }
```

below is the test case

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class BroadCastingServiceImplTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private BroadCastingServiceImpl broadCastingService;
    @Mock
    private EtaService etaService;

   @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        closeable = MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    }

    @AfterEach
    void tearDown() throws Exception {
        closeable.close();
    }

@Test
    @DisplayName("Given a valid request, when SearchSession and calculate eta is called, it should search Broadcasting session and return eta")
    void givenValidRequest_whenSearchSessionAndCalculateEta_shouldReturnBroadCastingResponseDTO() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException, IOException {
        // GIVEN
        UUID sessionId = UUID.randomUUID();
        DTO searchSessionAndCalculateETA = new DTO();
        searchSessionAndCalculateETA.setSessionId(sessionId.toString());
        searchSessionAndCalculateETA.setWaypoints(List.of("waypointsDTO", "waypointsDTO2"));
        given(etaService.entitiesEta("entitiesEtaRequestDTO")).willReturn(Mono.just(List.of("entitiesEtaResponseDTO")));

        // WHEN
        Mono<SearchSessionAndETAResponse> result = broadCastingService.searchSessionAndCalculateETA(searchSessionAndCalculateETA);
    }
}
```

The problem:

when i run test case the call does not go inside .map, .flatMap and .map even though dataFromRedis is not null.
Is there anything i am missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your test you just create the `Mono` but you don't actually "run" it, more precisely you do not subscribe to it.

Working with reactive code has two phases:

1. First you write the **specification** of the reactive stream, which tells **what** to do, but doesn't start the process. A `Mono` is only a fancy complex memory structure with a lot of lambda functions telling what will be done when it will be done.
2. Then you **subscribe** to the `Mono` - only this starts the whole process and starts calling all the lambdas. Only then the "call is going inside .map and .flatMap" to paraphrase your words :)

Read some tutorial, e.g. this Baeldung's [Intro To Reactor Core](https://www.baeldung.com/reactor-core).

If you just use `Mono` in simple Spring applications to handle REST endpoint, you may easily miss this because your `@RestController` just returns the `Mono` and the rest (*pun intended*) is handled by Spring. Spring **subscribes** to the `Mono` you returned from the controller methods and handles that the result is passed to the called via HTTP.

In **unit tests**, you can do it very simply just by calling its [`block()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#block--) method, or more properly by using [`StepVerifier`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/test/release/api/index.html?reactor/test/StepVerifier.html):

```
result.as(StepVerifier::create)
    .expectNext(objectToExpect)
    .verifyComplete();
```

Just using the `block()` method works more like a workaround. `StepVerifier` is the proper way of unit testing the reactive code.

Be careful not to just use the [`subscribe()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#subscribe--) method, because the test may finish before the subscription has time to perform and you will get unpredictable results.

Comment: thanks it helped.
we can also use:
SearchSessionAndETAResponse actualResponse = result.block();

Comment: @DivyaSingh But take into account that the proper way of unit testing is `StepVerifier`, with your expected result passed to `expectNext`! Calling `block()` is rather a workaround :)